# RequestNavigate in MainWindowViewModel ctor

Tags: wpf, prism

hi i want when application luanched, application navigate to a view automatically so i used like this:

```
 protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainContent>();

            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Subscene>();
        }
```

and in MainWindowViewModel

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _regionManager = regionManager;

            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "Subscene", myparameter);
        }
```

this code not work, No errors and no navigation

my region exist in another usercontrol called `MainContent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for "normal" view models only, not for the view model of the shell, because that one is created too early. You should do the initial navigation in `OnInitialized`.

```
internal class MyApp : PrismApplication
{
     // ...

     protected override void OnInitialized()
     {
         base.OnInitialized();
         Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>().RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "Subscene", myparameter);
     }

     // ...
}
```

Unrelated sidenote: if you use the parameter instead of the field in the constructor, Resharper will tell you when the field is no longer needed in future refactorings.